# how to import module in flask

Tags: python, flask

I just want to use flask to build a simple web, i tried with the code below:

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] ='thangvc91'
    return app
```

`main.py`

```
from web.template import create_app
app = create_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

it always said the error:

```
 "from web.template import create_app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web'
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.122 seconds"
```

can you assist on this ?
folder structures like below:

```
web - static
    - template - __init__.py
               - views.py
               - models.py
               - auth.py
    -main.py
```

Comment: Did you install it via `pip`?

Comment: use 
    from app import create_app

Comment: Try creating an empty `__init__.py` file in the 'web' directory to make it into a module.